# Why does the series $\sum_{n=1}^∞ \ln ({n \over n+1})$ diverges? And general tips about series and the logarithm

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Why does the series $\sum_{n=1}^∞ \ln ({n \over n+1})$ diverges? I'm looking for an answer using the comparison test, I'm just not sure what I can compare it to.

And can I have some tips on what to look at when handling with series that have logarithms in the expression?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We have $$\log\frac{n}{n+1}=\log n-\log (n+1)$$

Telescope, telescope, telescope.

Alternatively, $$\tag 1 \log\left(1+\frac{1}n\right)\sim\frac 1 n$$ as $n\to\infty$ cries out for the comparison test.

**ADD** Recall (or prove) that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}x=1$$

This means  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}n\right)}{\frac1n}=1$$
which is what I write in $(1)$.

Comment: Good one! Thanks.

Comment: Why is $\ln (1+{1 \over n})$ ~ ${1 \over n}$? And what's the general principle?

Comment: @ohad I added something. "the general principle"?

Comment: Nevermind. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The partial sum is telescopic
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n(\log(k+1)-\log k)=\log(n+1)-\log 1=\log(n+1)\to\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{n=1}^m \ln ({n \over n+1})
=\ln \prod_{n=1}^m ({n \over n+1})
= \ln \frac{1}{m+1}
$

and since
$\frac{1}{m+1} \to 0$
as $m \to =\infty$,
$\ln \frac{1}{m+1} \to -\infty$
as $m \to \infty$.